# Problem extracting value from Django object serialized as JSON

Tags: javascript, django, serialization

I have serialised a Django object using

`data = serializers.serialize("json", vchemicals)`

and passed it into my template, where it can be printed as:

```
[{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 1, "fields": {"shortname": "NaCl", "longname": "Sodium Chloride", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 2, "fields": {"shortname": "NH4SO4", "longname": "Ammonium Sulphate", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 3, "fields": {"shortname": "Glucose", "longname": "D-Glucose", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 4, "fields": {"shortname": "NaPO4", "longname": "Sodium Phosphate", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 5, "fields": {"shortname": "Glycerol", "longname": "Glycerol", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 6, "fields": {"shortname": "KCl", "longname": "Potassium Chloride", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 7, "fields": {"shortname": null, "longname": "Tryptone", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}, 
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 8, "fields": {"shortname": "Test", "longname": "Name that is clearly too long for the table", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}]
```

I set this as a JS variable within a script using

```
var chemlist = "{{ data }}";
```

It is now printed as

```
[{&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 1, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;NaCl&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Sodium Chloride&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 2, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;NH4SO4&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Ammonium Sulphate&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 3, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;Glucose&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;D-Glucose&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 4, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;NaPO4&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Sodium Phosphate&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 5, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;Glycerol&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Glycerol&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 6, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;KCl&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Potassium Chloride&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 7, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: null, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Tryptone&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}, {&quot;model&quot;: &quot;vbench.vchemical&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 8, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;shortname&quot;: &quot;Test&quot;, &quot;longname&quot;: &quot;Name that is clearly too long for the table&quot;, &quot;catno&quot;: null, &quot;batchno&quot;: 1, &quot;owner&quot;: 1}}]
```

and when I try to reference the first item using

```
chemlist[0]
```

I get

```
[
```

instead of what I want, which is:

```
{"model": "vbench.vchemical", "pk": 1, "fields": {"shortname": "NaCl", "longname": "Sodium Chloride", "catno": null, "batchno": 1, "owner": 1}}
```

Could someone tell me where I have gone please? I want to access the field values (shortname, longname, etc.) using the pk values as a key.

edit: AJAX/jQuery used to solve this problem added

Template Code:

```
    <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("chemicalrow");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var theid = this.id;
        var data = {theid};
        console.log(data)
        $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url :  "{% url 'get_chemical_data' %}",
          data : data,
          success : function(response){
            document.getElementById("snamebox").value=response.chem_info.sname
            document.getElementById("lnamebox").value=response.chem_info.lname
            document.getElementById("catnobox").value=response.chem_info.catno
            document.getElementById("batchnobox").value=response.chem_info.batchno
          },
          error : function(response){
            console.log(response)
          }
        })
       })
    }
    </script>
```

views.py

```
def getChemicalData(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        theid = request.GET.get("theid")

        try:
            chemical = vChemical.objects.get(id = theid)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"success":False}, status=400)
        chem_info = {
            "sname": chemical.shortname,
            "lname": chemical.longname,
            "catno": chemical.catno,
            "batchno": chemical.batchno,
        }
        return JsonResponse({"chem_info":chem_info}, status=200)
    return JsonResponse({"success":False}, status=400)
```

Comment: It's really not a good idea to insert dynamic (ie: template) elements within JavaScript (XSS). If possible, try to create an API view that just answer a JSON, and try to retrieve the content from an Ajax / XHR request in JS. This kind of request keep your cookie / session feature, so you'll be able to get user specific elements from within the view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a step back and learn the AJAX/jQuery basics for now.

Comment: For anybody else trying to incorporate AJAX/jQuery into their Django project, I finally learned enough about it to solve the problem above. Big thanks to guides from W3 and Jai Singhal (https://djangopy.org/learn/step-up-guide-to-implement-ajax-in-django/) for helping me along.